# Как получить username бота от которого пришло обновление?

Tags: php, telegram, бот

Я создаю линейку ботов, где главная функция это копирование бота (функционала) с помощью токена пользователя. Пользователь отправляет токен моему боту, а я подключаю его к своему серверу и передаю функционал

Когда пользователь нажимает inline_keyboard кнопку, я вижу юзернейм от бота, но когда я отправлю ему сообщение, то вижу только отправителя.

Что я хочу сделать в коде. Пользователь отправил токен, я используя getMe получил username бота и сохранил все эти данные. Когда пользователь что-то делает в боте, я получаю username бота, ищу у себя его токен, и отвечаю.

Проблема в том, что я не вижу username бота, когда пользователь отправляет ему сообщение, а в любых других моментах вижу, например при нажатии кнопки под сообщением.

Подскажите как реализовать задачу или костыль. Я не использую библиотеки, только чистый php

Comment: а sendMessage происходит по id бота? Если да, то думаю логично будет хранить где то ``id - username`` и найти и выводить username по id

Comment: @YaMus если честно не понял что Вы имеете ввиду. Когда я отправляю сообщение боту (текст) то мне приходит обновление, где и в chat и from ключах json указан отправитель (пользователь, юзер, человек), но в других моментах, где работает программа я вижу юзернейм бота в chat и данные пользователя в from ключах

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось проще, чем было в моей голове.

В момент, когда пользователь отправил токен моему боту, я создал файл с токеном, внутри него прописал `include(“my_script.php”)`, и повесил вебхук на созданный файл.

Теперь, когда приходит обновление от любого бота, мне не нужен юзернейм бота, чтобы достать токен в БД - токен изначально прописан в файле, куда приходят обновления, где подключается программа.